# how to add another readme in nested folder and image into readme in a github repo?

Tags: git, github, readme

my sql exercises [github repo](https://github.com/erjan/sql_exercises) contains my solutions i have gotten so far from various popular sql trainers.

It has subfolders, each subfolder is for different website with exercises.

I need to add separate readme describing where the solutions, exercises come from.

git allows this?

Comment: Git is a version control system. You can add any (well, almost any) files to any directory you want. Will GitHub display it as expected? That's a different question, but I guess yes, it will display them. Why don't you try it out? In a branch which can be deleted afterwards, for instance.

Comment: yep it does work! just name the readme.md and  i have another readme in subfolder..